# Issue unistalling old kernels on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, kernel, 20.04

Hi i'm experiencing an issue when removing old kernels on Ubuntu 20.04

when i run apt autoremove it says that there aren't any packages that need to be removed, and if I try to remove a kernel from my self apt automaticcaly install the unsigned version for that kernel (also trying to remove the unsigned version reinstall back the signed one).  I have almost ten kernels that i dont use installed and i want to free space on my root partion. Any Suggest?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
```

```
 dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-28-generic                  5.4.0-28.32                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic                  5.4.0-29.33                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-31-generic                  5.4.0-31.35                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic                  5.4.0-33.37                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic                  5.4.0-37.41                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic                  5.4.0-39.43                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic                  5.4.0-40.44                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic                  5.4.0-42.46                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic                  5.4.0-45.49                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic                  5.4.0-47.51                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                           5.4.0.47.50                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

```
sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
I seguenti pacchetti aggiuntivi saranno inoltre installati:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-29-generic
Pacchetti suggeriti:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.4.0 linux-tools
I seguenti pacchetti saranno RIMOSSI:
  linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic* linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-29-generic*
I seguenti pacchetti NUOVI saranno installati:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-29-generic
0 aggiornati, 1 installati, 2 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
È necessario scaricare 8.895 kB di archivi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno liberati 30,9 MB di spazio su disco.
Continuare? [S/n]
```

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu

EDIT2:

I'm done some more research and i figure out the problem. Seems that the kernels were marked as manual installation, using this command `sudo apt-mark auto $(apt-mark showmanual | grep -E "^linux-([[:alpha:]]+-)+[[:digit:].]+-[^-]+(|-.+)$")` i was able to remark them as automatic installation and then apt autoremove recognized them for the removal. Thanks for you help, hope this can be usefull for others too.

Comment: Are you able to [edit] your post putting the exact sequence of commands that you run and related terminal output messages?

Comment: Hi @LorenzKeel i added the commands into the post

Comment: I've tested it in a virtual machine. I confirm that when I remove the `linux-image-XXX-generic`,  `apt` automatically installs the unsigned version, but when I remove the unsigned version the related signed version does NOT come back. Consider also that typically the signed version typically consumes more disk space than the unsigned version (in your example, 30 MB against 8 MB), so you may not care about the unsigned ones because the purpose to get more space is satisfied.

Comment: I'm done some more research and i figure out the problem. Seems that the kernels were marked as manual installation, using this command ```sudo apt-mark auto $(apt-mark showmanual | grep -E "^linux-([[:alpha:]]+-)+[[:digit:].]+-[^-]+(|-.+)$")``` i was able to remark them as automatic installation and then apt autoremove recognized them for the removal. Thanks for you help, hope this can be usefull for others too.

Comment: If you have enough reputation to do it, you can add an answer with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm done some more research and i figure out the problem. Seems that the kernels were marked as manual installation, using this command `sudo apt-mark auto $(apt-mark showmanual | grep -E "^linux-([[:alpha:]]+-)+[[:digit:].]+-[^-]+(|-.+)$")` i was able to remark them as automatic installation and then apt autoremove recognized them for the removal. Thanks for you help, hope this can be usefull for others too.